# Query multiple oracle schemas in LINQPAD with IQ driver

Tags: linq, oracle, linqpad

Is it possible to query multiple schemas in Linqpad with the IQ connection driver for oracle?

E.G.  I have a user that can see two schemas ,*users* and *customers*.  Currently I have to specify the schema I want to use when setting up the connection.  So, I can only query one schema per session.  It would be great if I could do something like the following:

```
var customers = from c in *customers*.sometable
                select c;
var users = from u in *users*.sometable
             select u;
...
```

in a single session.  Is such a thing possible with any existing oracle drivers in LINQPad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cannot be done at the moment: when the driver builds a typed datacontext, it creates objects for just one schema. Why don't you register a request in linqpad.uservoice.com - a few other people have asked about this.